# How to read the value of toggle switch in winjs app

Tags: winjs

I have tried the below code for getting checked value of toggle switch button. But I am unable to find the checked property of toggle switch in JavaScript method.

.js:

```
var yammerpt = document.getElementById("toggleSwitch").winControl;
```

.html:

```
<div id="toggleSwitch" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch" data-win-options="{labelOn:'Post to Yammer', labelOff:'Post to Yammer', checked:true}">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229743.aspx) property is what you're looking for.

```
var yammerpt = document.getElementById("toggleSwitch").winControl; //here you get the control itself
var checked = yammerpt.checked;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - the 'checked' property of the winControl is what you want.

Take a look at this code sample:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ToggleSwitch-control-sample-84c0aacb

And here's the official documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229743.aspx